# Add Two Fields That May Contain NULL - SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to add two fields that may contain a NULL value in an SSRS expression.  On records that contain a NULL, I am getting an #Error on the report interface.

I have tried to handle the NULLs with the following:

```
=SUM( IIF(IsNothing(Fields!TotalSale.Value),0,Fields!TotalSale.Value) + IIF(IsNothing(Fields!TotalVoidedSale.Value),0,Fields!TotalVoidedSale.Value) )
```

and:

```
=SUM( IIF(IsNothing(Fields!TotalSale.Value),Nothing,Fields!TotalSale.Value) + IIF(IsNothing(Fields!TotalVoidedSale.Value),Nothing,Fields!TotalVoidedSale.Value) )
```

And neither works.  Could someone point out what I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for detail-level data, then you would want to simply remove the SUM and go with this:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!TotalSale.Value),0,Fields!TotalSale.Value) + IIF(IsNothing(Fields!TotalVoidedSale.Value),0,Fields!TotalVoidedSale.Value)
```

If you need this expression as an aggregate, then you would need two add the two separate sums together:

```
=SUM(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!TotalSale.Value),0,Fields!TotalSale.Value)) + SUM(IIF(IsNothing(Fields!TotalVoidedSale.Value),0,Fields!TotalVoidedSale.Value))
```

Comment: Thanks - I'm going to test this out.